# jquery kwicks issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on my problem for the past few hours and am at the end of my rope.  I need help.

I have a staging page where I tested the code and verfied that it works, but on the live page, the code refuses to budge.  I can't figure out why kwicks jq seems to be ignoring the html on the jujumamablog.com header. <-- this is my question.

I'm using the kwicks for jQuery.  I created a working sample page so I could be sure that the code was working before trying to integrate into the live area of the site.  The sample page can be found here: http://jujumamablog.com/jujumama/dev.html

The code for the *working*sample page is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Kwicks Examples: Example 1</title>
    <script src="http://jmar777.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jmar777.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://kwicks.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v1.5.1/Kwicks/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <style type="text/css">

    /* defaults for all examples */
    .kwicks {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .kwicks li{
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* example 1 */
    #example1 .kwicks li{
        float: left;
        width: 98px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }
    #example1 #kwick1 { 
        background-color: #53b388;
    }
    #example1 #kwick2 {
        background-color: #5a69a9;
    }
    #example1 #kwick3 {
        background-color: #c26468;
    }
    #example1 #kwick4 { 
        background-color: #bf7cc7;
    }
    #example1 #kwick5 { 
        background-color: #bf7cc7;
        margin-right: none;
    }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $('.kwicks').kwicks({
            max : 205,
            spacing : 5
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
        <div id="example1">
            <ul class="kwicks">

                <li id="kwick1"></li>
                <li id="kwick2"></li>
                <li id="kwick3"></li>
                <li id="kwick4"></li>
                <li id="kwick5"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</body>
```

I was hoping that this would be a fairly simple 'plug-and-play' instance.  Boy, was I wrong.

My task was to get this slick piece running smoothly.  I know there are other issues with the main site (jujumamablog.com), load time specifically, which I was told to ignore for the time being.

***Edit***-----------

I need to be a bit more clear here.  The above code works, I'm wondering why, when I try to put the code into the live page (jujumamablog.com, where there are other scripts and -ish) that this *stops* working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me (in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for your input Greg, although, as I thought I made clear in my description the testing area is working as expected.  The header instance at jujumama.com is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are including jQuery a second time, and since all those plugins are just methods of jQuery, you blow them all away.

The first one is on line 65, and the second is on line 91. All the plugins added between those two, are destroyed.

As a side note, you should consider consolidating all those scripts into one, then compress them with YUI compressor or whatever you prefer, and finally, if possible, put it at the bottom instead of at the top.

Comment: I didn't know you were a Stackoverflow member ;)

Comment: I still see double jQuery on the site, ivannovak.
Do you have a dev site or something where I can see the changes?

Hey meder! :D

Comment: Try it again, I hadn't realized that wp_head(); brought in its own version of jquery.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Now you are including the plugins before jQuery, so they explode because they can't find jQuery. :)
If you can, hop into #jquery on Freenode.

Comment: Since taking out the jQuery that I linked, I put the necessary scripts below wp_head();.  I now get the error '$(document).ready is not a function'

Answer (score 1):

The `$().ready(function() {` looks wrong to me. I thought that the two ways of doing it were

```
$(function()
{
    //etc
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //etc
});
```

Comment: I edited the question, for clarity.  The above code works, I'm wondering why it stops working when I put it on the live site (jujumamablog.com)

Answer (score 0):

I get an error on this line:

```
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
```

> [Exception] TypeError: Object # has no method 'superfish'

It's possible this is stopping the rest of your ready events from firing.

Comment: I deleted that line and the associated lines.  Still no go. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is that your live server uses a newer version of Jquery. I have the same problems but I don't know what's different between 1.2.6 and 1.4.2. Hopefully some answers will turn up!

Now I'm asking here: [Plugin: Kwicks for Jquery works perfectly with Jquery 1.2.6 but not 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803010/plugin-kwicks-for-jquery-works-perfectly-with-jquery-1-2-6-but-not-1-4-2)